# Including yaml-cpp without Boost available -

Tags: yaml-cpp

Perhaps this is a naive question - but is there a way to build/install yaml-cpp so that you don't need to have the Boost library headers around when building a project that includes yaml.h?

IE: I have a project I'm working on that uses yaml-cpp structures and parsing.  On the system it will be deployed on I do not have Boost installed (no library or headers).  Building said project on a system with Boost is no issue - but when building on the system without Boost headers it fails since yaml-cpp directly includes Boost headers.

cmake output:

```
/yaml_install_path/include/yaml-cpp/node/ptr.h", line 10: catastrophic error: 
          cannot open source file "boost/shared_ptr.hpp"
  #include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
```

Is there a way to get around this short of manually installing that header file somewhere on the system?  I was hoping to get this sorted out so that yaml-cpp could be linked to (and used) in other projects without relying on Boost at all.  I'd rather not depend on Boost at all if possible.

Thanks in advance - hopefully there is a clean fix to this and I just missed something simple. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that's not possible. However, yaml-cpp does have a separate branch, version 0.3.x, that uses an old API with no dependency on Boost.

Comment: That's unfortunate.  Thanks for answering (and so quickly too)!